# subset a table to include rows associated with only one occurence of a set of entries

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table for 4 individuals with their favorite fruit:

`tbl`:

```
ID         FRUIT
personA    banana
personB    apple
personC    orange
personD    grapefruit
personA    avocado
personB    banana
personC    melon
personD    pear
personA    banana
```

I would like to extract all the entries for the IDs that are associated with only one of the following: banana, apple, orange.

This means that I am only hoping to extract the rows for person A and person C. person B has both ("apple" AND "banana"). person D has none of the three desired fruits.

I currently have:

```
select *
from tbl t1
where exists (select 1
              from tbl t2
              where t1.ID=t2.ID and
                    (t2.fruit='banana' or
                     t2.fruit='apple' or
                     t2.fruit='orange'))
join (select ID, count(*) over (partition by t3.fruit)
      from (select distinct ID, fruit
              from tbl
              where fruit='banana' or
                    fruit='apple' or
                    fruit='orange')) t3
on t3.ID=t.ID and
   t3.cnt=1
```

Is there a better/simpler way to execute this? I would like to optimize it to reduce run time given the tables are quite large.

`desired table`:

```
ID         FRUIT
personA    banana
personC    orange
personA    avocado
personC    melon
personA    banana
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with snowflake but something like this would work. Still uses a subquery but might be a little more efficient than the above https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9811073704aa9fe2cd6a120da06e3c9

Comment: @nbk - You sure? Seems to ... https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/having.html

Comment: oh i missed that thx @SOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery determines all IDs which have those three fruits and count how many individual fruits they have.

You know can join the ID to the table and only take those IDs which have only 1 fruit, if you also want three fruits you and add this in the join condition

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID, FRUIT
FROM
    tbl t1
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        ID, COUNT(DISTINCT FRUIT) countf
    FROM
        tbl
    WHERE
        FRUIT IN ('banana', 'apple', 'orange')
    GROUP BY 1) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t2.countf = 1;
```

Comment: This solution works if you fix the in to be `('banana', 'apple', 'orange')` and the first select of ID is changed to `t1.id` or `t2.id` to resolve the ambiguous column.

Answer (score 1):

We can use GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT) to find the persons we want.

> ```
> SELECT 
>   a.ID,
>   b.FRUITID
> FROM tb1 a
> JOIN tb1 b ON a.ID = b.ID
> WHERE a.FRUITID IN ('banana', 'apple', 'orange')
> GROUP BY 
>   a.ID,
>   b.FRUITID
> HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.FRUITID) = 1;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID      | FRUITID
> :------ | :------
> personA | avocado
> personA | banana 
> personC | melon  
> personC | orange
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5e09060e08b87327b0dcfad1c5afcb4)*

Comment: Compared to the example output this does not repeat the personA second banana

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach is to use [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl t
QUALIFY COUNT_IF(t.fruit = 'banana') OVER(PARTITION BY ID) = 1
    AND COUNT_IF(t.fruit = 'apple')  OVER(PARTITION BY ID) = 1
    AND COUNT_IF(t.fruit = 'orange') OVER(PARTITION BY ID) = 1;
```

Comment: This gives zero rows output. As none of the users have 1 of each of the three fruit.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer:

This can be done with:

```
select *
from data
qualify count( distinct iff(fruit in ('apple','banana','orange'), fruit, null)) 
           over(partition by id) = 1
```

which gives:

| ID | FRUIT |
| --- | --- |
| personA | avocado |
| personA | banana |
| personA | banana |
| personC | melon |
| personC | orange |

### How that works:

this can be shown how it works by showing the intermediate state of the [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html) and the [COUNT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count.html) DISTINCT like so:

```
select *
    ,iff(fruit in ('apple','banana','orange'), fruit, null) as v
    ,count( distinct v) over(partition by id) as c
from data
```

gives:

| ID | FRUIT | V | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| personA | avocado |  | 1 |
| personA | banana | banana | 1 |
| personA | banana | banana | 1 |
| personB | apple | apple | 2 |
| personB | banana | banana | 2 |
| personC | melon |  | 1 |
| personC | orange | orange | 1 |
| personD | grapefruit |  | 0 |
| personD | pear |  | 0 |

Thus `personD` is eliminated for have no magic fruit, and `personB` is eliminated for have too much.

If you are deeply caring about performance (which I would test) I assume nbk's solution would perform the fastest.

Comment: hmm, it strange to down vote the only answer that gives the correct answer. maybe also as I didn't down vote the other three answers which are all wrong. But did provide feedback, so those authors can fix there solutions.